# Selecting static fields via dropdown at Designtime in C#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2015, typeconverter, uitypeeditor

Is it possible to modify a `ComponentConverter`, `Typeconverter`,... so I can select "Components" that are in a static class outside the form?

When I create a custom control and add a property of type `Component` or `Control` I get a dropdown menu in designer where I can select one ot the existing ones.

The reference to the selected object is automatically added in the designer code.

Problem is, that the dropdown only lets me select components that were declared in this form or a form that this form inherits, but no other form or a static class.

But I want to have one specific file in my solution where I can declare all these components once, an then use them in each form (I have several in my project) at designtime.

[image: Image of static declaring class]

When I add the reference to the static objects myself in designer code, everything works fine, but this is not comfortable, because I have to alter the code manually.

[image: screenshot of the designer code, last line]

Would it be possible to modify a `Converter` or `UITypeEditor`, so it can select static objects and then pass them to the designer?

I tried to override a ComponentConverter, but in the designer code it only writes "null" instead of the object:

```
class MyConverter : ComponentConverter
{
    public MyConverter(Type type) : base(type)
    {
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return new StandardValuesCollection(new List<BOOL>() { Variablen.M0_2, Variablen.M0_3, Variablen.M0_4 });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can probably do this with a `PropertyDescriptor`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Looks very complex to me, but I will try to get into this

Comment: You will likely have to dig into the `System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization` namespace in System.Design.dll. Hairy stuff (but fun). `MemberCodeDomSerializer` will be used in the pipeline from what I can see.

Comment: Thank you too. Seems I will have to learn a lot of new things the next days ;)

Comment: Hm, this is trickier than I thought
But it must be possible. System.Drawing.Color is similar
All named colors are also static vars a static class, and if you select the named color in the propertygrid at the designtime, also the reference is inserted like:     
this.myButton1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

Thats the same i want to achieve with my custom class
the only thing Color is usin is a `UITypeEditor` and a `TypeConverter`

Comment: `System.Drawing.ColorConverter` is doing exactly what I need. Parsing a string to a reference of a static struct like `System.Drawing.Color.Black`
But my own TypeConverters always fail to do so...

Comment: I will look into that and provide feedback tomorrow if I can see what happens there. For now, try making static properties (I know there is not a field capable convertor so that is what may be blocking it).

Comment: Thanks to [Microsoft Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) I could look inside the `ColorConverter` and fork it to play around with it. Seems that this works with `Colors`, because they are `struct` (value-type). But I want that functionality for `class` (reference-type)

Comment: Today I will try to analyze the source of ComponentConverter and Component, maxbe that gives me a hint

Comment: `ComponentConverter` is using `IReferenceService`. I will investigate that further

Comment: Seems I really have to use `CodeDomSerializer` I just managed to modify the designer code the way I need. Hopefully I will be able to post a working solution soon (if everything works out as I need to)

Comment: Good luck :) Will be nice to see your solution.

Comment: Thanks. I think this will take a little while. The code is very crappy and buggy at the time ;)

Comment: @drvolcano Well, you could always have a `struct` that wraps the `class` :P

Comment: Meanwhile I have managed to get 90% of the code working as I wanted :D
Still a little bit buggy, but I think I will be able to post my solution till the weekend

Answer (score 0):

After some work, I got this working, but stability is not the best. Sometimes after compiling I get errors, because context or service is null in the `TypeConverter`

Base-class:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyReferenceTypeonverter))]
[DesignerSerializer(typeof(MyObjectSerializer), typeof(CodeDomSerializer))]
public abstract class MyReferencableObject
{
    internal FieldInfo FieldInfo { get; set; }

    //Could also use: FieldInfo.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + FieldInfo.Name;
    public string FullName { get { return FieldInfo.DeclaringType.Name + "." + FieldInfo.Name; } }
}
```

Serializer:

```
public class MyObjectSerializer : CodeDomSerializer
{
    public override object Serialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, object value)
    {
        return new CodeVariableReferenceExpression((value as MyReferencableObject).FullName);
    }
}`
```

Container

```
 /// <summary>
/// Prototype for class that whrer MyReferencableObject are declared
/// </summary>
public abstract class Deklaration
{

}
```

TypeConverter

```
public class MyReferenceTypeonverter : TypeConverter
{
    private Type ContainerType = typeof(Deklaration);

    private const string empty = "(none)";


    Dictionary<string, MyReferencableObject> values;

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        string FullName = (string)value;

        if (FullName == empty)
            return null;

        InitDict(context);

        if (values.ContainsKey(FullName))
            return values[FullName];

        return value;
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return empty;

        InitDict(context);

        foreach (string key in values.Keys)
            if (key != empty)
                if (values[key].FullName == ((MyReferencableObject)value).FullName)
                    return key;

        //sometimes happens...
        return "ERROR!!!";
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        InitDict(context);
        return new StandardValuesCollection(values.Values);
    }

    void InitDict(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        //sometimes happens...
        if (context == null)
            return;

        Dictionary<string, MyReferencableObject> tvalues = new Dictionary<string, MyReferencableObject>();
        tvalues.Add(empty, null);

        ITypeDiscoveryService Service = (ITypeDiscoveryService)context.GetService(typeof(ITypeDiscoveryService));

        //sometimes happens...
        if (Service == null)
            return;

        foreach (Type declaration in Service.GetTypes(ContainerType, false))
            foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in declaration.GetFields())
                if (context.PropertyDescriptor.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(fieldInfo.FieldType))
                {
                    MyReferencableObject var = (MyReferencableObject)fieldInfo.GetValue(null);
                    var.FieldInfo = fieldInfo;
                    tvalues.Add(var.FullName, var);
                }

        //in a perfect world the if should not be necessary....
        if (tvalues.Count > 1 || values == null)
            values = tvalues;
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value, attributes);
    }
}
```