# Getting the own static instance name at design-time

Tags: c#, design-time

Is it possible to override `ToString()`, so a class it returns its own instance-name, when declared static?

I only need this at design-time, not during execution.

```
public class MyVar
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return MY_NAME();
    }
}

public class Vars
{
    public static MyVar a = new MyVar(); //ToString() returns "a" or "Vars.a"
    public static MyVar b = new MyVar(); //ToString() returns "b" or "Vars.b"
    public static MyVar c = new MyVar(); //ToString() returns "c" or "Vars.c"
    public static MyVar d = new MyVar(); //ToString() returns "d" or "Vars.d"
}
```

Background: I want to show this name in the propertygrid of the designer:

```
        this.myButton2.Text = "myButton2";
        this.myButton2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.myButton2.Reference = Vars.b;//Should be displayed in the PropertyGrid as "b" or "Vars.b"
```

Comment: Sure, I use enums very often, but they dont help here. I am currently playing arount with CodeDomSerializer and TypeConverter, to make it posisible to select a static class in the propertygrid at designtime [See my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759065/selecting-static-fields-via-dropdown-at-designtime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What is `myButton2.Reference`?

Comment: @David: Reference is a representation of a tag in a S7-PLC. I want to create a HMI framework for visual studio, and "Reference" is used to connect the HMI-control to the tag in the PLC. It holds all functions and data for writing and reading this tag (for a button this wold be BOOL, which is set on preess and reset on release)

Comment: Reference is of type MyVar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

References are just that - a reference to an instance. They are not *named*. The local or field you use to store the reference can have a name, but there's no way to get from the reference to the field other than by trying to compare each in turn - for example:

```
void Main()
{
  Vars.a.ToString().Dump();
  Vars.b.ToString().Dump();
  Vars.c.ToString().Dump();
  Vars.d.ToString().Dump();
}

public class MyVar
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var field = typeof(Vars)
                    .GetFields()
                    .Where(i => object.ReferenceEquals(i.GetValue(null), this))
                    .FirstOrDefault();

        return field == null ? "Unknown" : field.Name;
    }
}

public class Vars
{
    public static MyVar a = new MyVar(); //ToString() returns "a" or "Vars.a"
    public static MyVar b = new MyVar(); //ToString() returns "b" or "Vars.b"
    public static MyVar c = new MyVar(); //ToString() returns "c" or "Vars.c"
    public static MyVar d = new MyVar(); //ToString() returns "d" or "Vars.d"
}
```

However, this is certainly a code smell - you shouldn't really need something like that.

Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, there's probably a lot of much cleaner approaches. For example, you could use something like this:

```
public class MyVar
{
  public static readonly MyVar a = new MyVar(nameof(a));
  public static readonly MyVar b = new MyVar(nameof(b));
  public static readonly MyVar c = new MyVar(nameof(c));
  public static readonly MyVar d = new MyVar(nameof(d));

  private readonly string name;
  private MyVar(string name) { this.name = name; }

  override string ToString() { return this.name; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, that was the last part of the puzzle I needed :)

Comment: And: you are totally right, that is maybe not the best way to do things, but I have my reasons ;)

Answer (score 0):

`MyVar` itself cannot do this as impossible to resolve situations all too easily arise, eg what would `.ToString()` return for the following code:

```
public static MyVar a = new MyVar(); 
public static MyVar b = a;  // Should ToString() return "a" or "b"?
```

If you are using C#6, then `nameof` could be used to return the name of the variable:

```
this.myButton2.Reference = nameof(Vars.b);
```

though I'm unclear on what `Reference` is here, so that may not work.